# Knockout js working with the foreach control flow and radion as template

Tags: knockout.js

The 'checked' binding is not very compatible for radio button that generated by a foreach control flow.

example:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: targetAudience">
        <div>
            <label>
                <input name="targetAudience" type="radio"  data-bind="checked:    isSelected,value:id" />
                <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

each vm(single target) will get the id of the selected radio at the isSelected property.
This looks a little smelly, is there a better way to know who is the selected radio?

Comment: What do you want `isSelected` to be set to?  Also, you would want to use `attr: { value: id }` rather than the `value` binding as you don't want multiple event handlers attached to it.

Comment: I want isSelected to be false on all radio that are unchecked and true in the checked one.

Comment: please explain your comment, I think I'm missing something, what do you men multiple event handlers.

Comment: The `value` binding adds an event handler to try to update the model when an input is changed.  The `checked` binding does this as well and knows how to handle radio buttons appropriately.  So, you really only want to use `checked` and then use `attr: { value: yourValue }` to just keep the `value` attribute in sync (with no other functionality added)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'checked' binding when working with radio buttons is designed to populate the model with the "value" of the individual radio button rather than update a flag on each item in an array.

An easy way to make this work though is to have it populate a value on the parent and then add a computed observable on each item to determine whether its selected flag should be true or false.

Here is a sample:

```
var Item = function(id, name, selected) {
   this.id = id;
   this.name = ko.observable(name);
   this.selected = ko.computed(function() {
        return parseInt(selected(), 10) == this.id;  
   }, this);
};

var ViewModel = function() {
    this.selected = ko.observable(2);
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
        new Item(1, "one", this.selected),
        new Item(2, "two", this.selected),
        new Item(3, "three", this.selected)
       ]);
};
```

Then, bind like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="items" data-bind="attr: { value: id }, checked: $root.selected" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/zNkhR/

Comment: In the computed method, how does ko/js knows that the selected() inside the parseInt belongs to the view model?

Comment: In this case, `selected` is passed to the constructor function for an Item and is available to the computed observable function via the closure.

Comment: ohh, didn't notice that, tanks

Comment: Am I missing something or is the Item.selected never called? I deleted it in your jsfiddle and there was no change to the functionality. Update: Never mind. I guess you would used it elsewhere.